# C enter a if block when the condition is false

Tags: c

A bitmap sort programme,in which the assign part is:

```
for(i = MAX/64-1;i >= 0;i--){
    for(j = 0;j < 64;j++){
        if(0 != (arr[i] & (1 << j))){
            *p++ = j + 64 * i;  
        }   
    }   
}
```

I gdb it,sometimes when the if condition returns 0 and the program still enter the block and execute the statement:
`*p++ = j + 64 *i;`
which cause segmentfault at last,I just don't understand under which circumstance would it happen

example:
when gdb status like this:
j=44, i=6250, arr[i]=4096  and `print (arr[i] & (1 << j))` gives 0
but programme still enter the block

Comment: Can you please explain where p points.

Comment: What is the data type of your array `arr[]` ? `int64_t` ?

Comment: One. You're using `&` which you probably shouldn't. Two. I assume `j` is an `int` - that is, it's barely 64 bits long. Since it's an int, and so is the `1` literal, the result is also treated as an int, which overflows (usually after the 31th bit).

Comment: You are left-shifting `1` up to `63`. If the type of `1` (`int`) has fewer than this many bits, then you have undefined behaviour.

Comment: @H2CO3: `&` is the right choice for a bitmask check.

Comment: @DCoder Of course, it is. But I don't know what OP wants to do by this (because he didn't write his intent), and it's a common beginner mistake to use `&` instead of `&&`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess is that you have 32 bit ints but your array data type is `int64_t`. In which case you need to change:

```
    if(0 != (arr[i] & (1 << j))){
```

to:

```
    if(0 != (arr[i] & (1LL << j))){
```

since `1 << j` is undefined for `j >= sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` (i.e. `j >= 32` in your case).

Comment: ... assuming that `long` is also 64 bits.

Comment: @Charles: sorry, yes, I was assuming LP64 - now changed to from `L` to `LL`.

Comment: Thanks for help,forgive the noob.. :<

Comment: Pedantic note: `1 << j` is undefined behaviour if `j` is greater than or equal to the _width_ of `int`, the width can be smaller than `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT`, since there could be padding bits. Ain't gonna happen in practice, but...

Answer (score 3):

`1 << j` is not very well-defined if it's `int` and `j` is greater than or equal to `CHAR_BIT * sizeof (int)`. This might be a problem since you use `j = 44` in your example.